# Is this language regular?

Tags: finite-automata

Is a language that accepts n(n-1)(n-2)/6+n(n-1)/2+1 many numbers of {0,1}^n for every n is a regular language?

I have a question to draw the dfa of those language, but I'm not even sure whether it is a regular one.

Comment: Could you post what you have tried? Also, check out [JFLAP](http://www.jflap.org/). It helped immensely in my CS theory class (specifically the test/input-output feature).

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like homework, and I'm guessing the question is: draw a DFA that accepts exactly n(n-1)(n-2)/6+n(n-1)/2+1 words of length n (over the alphabet {0,1}). Lets construct the automaton as an intersection of two DFAs.

The first automaton accepts words of length n. This is very easy - there is a chain of n+1 states. The first state is the initial state, only the last state is accepting, and every state has a transition labeled 0,1 to the next state in the chain. The accepting state has no outgoing transitions.

The second automaton accepts words in which there is one, two, or three 1s. Also, very easy - we need 4 states: q_0, q_1, q_2, q_sink. The state q_0 is the initial state, the states q_0,q_1,q_2 are accepting, and they have a self loop with 0. There are transitions q_0 --1--> q_1 --1--> q_2 --1--> q_sink. Finally, q_sink is rejecting and it has a self loop with 0,1.

In order to construct the intersection of the automata we need the product of the two automata. This is a general construction which also isn't very hard.